# Unable to understand MS-Word 2007 document encryption

Tags: encryption, hash, ms-word, ms-office, reverse-engineering

Ok so here goes my doubt a third time, after being rejected on security and superuser :(

So I read the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd910529%28v=office.12%29.aspx)
[This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/os_binaryfile/thread/309d750f-f5c7-4bcc-809f-7c879e2c2b8c/) answer also helped.

It seems there are 3 principal modes of encryption. I created a mock document and made it password protected. After some snooping, I guess my document uses the RC4 Encryption method. Here is the encryption header located at `0x1200` address:

```
01 00 01 00 27 cf 34 9f a9 86 50 53 ad 66 58 e9 
42 c4 bb 8c 11 00 41 26 f1 a9 37 d7 6e 1c d0 37 
3d fb 97 02 a6 9b c0 8f 71 df 28 a2 6b 6f 83 69 
fc 69 57 e3 70 a9 9d fc b3 8d 4f 35 0e ff d0 8c 
da b2 b5 67 0f 50 40 6b b8 54 58 e2 41 8e f3 f8
```

According to the document, the first 4 bytes are the major, minor versions followed by Salt, EncryptedVerifier, EncryptedVerifierHash each 16 bytes.

The key derivation algorithm is given [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd920360%28v=office.12%29.aspx):

The password for my document is `x` (single character). I am trying to derive the `EncryptedVerifier` first (which I think is a random number). However, I am getting different results :(
The encrypted key derivation algorithm is pretty straightforward till deriving the **TruncatedHash**. After this I am confused as to what I should do.

I am simply taking the `EncryptedVerifier` from the document and decrypting it using the RC4 algorithm using the key as `MD5(TruncatedHash + 00000000).` But when I hash this and compare it with the `EncryptedVerifierHash` (after decryption), the two results are different.

A part of the code is:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> h0 = hashlib.md5()
>>> h0.update('x')
>>> h0 = h0.hexdigest()
>>> h0
'9dd4e461268c8034f5c8564e155c67a6'
>>> h0tr = h0[0:10]
>>> h0tr
'9dd4e46126'
>>> ibuff = h0tr + '27cf349fa9865053ad6658e942c4bb8c'
>>> buff = ibuff * 16
>>> len(buff)/2
336
>>> h1 = hashlib.md5()
>>> h1.update(buff)
>>> h1 = h1.hexdigest()
>>> h1tr = h1[0:10]
>>> hf = hashlib.md5()
>>> hf.update(h1tr + '00000000')
>>> hf = hf.hexdigest()
>>> hf
'43e94942913b933273f5c65d3c859723'
```

I am using [this](http://rc4.online-domain-tools.com/) website for the RC4 encryption/decryption.

What am I doing wrong? Let me know if you need additional contents from the document.
Thanks!